# Error when reading from text file

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

I keep getting this error when reading from a text file it gets the first few numbers but then does this there also shouldnt be 0's in there, tried a lot of things not sure what to do. I have to be able to read the file numbers and then multiply specific ones could use some help thanks. (I was using the final println to check what numbers it was getting). Sorry forgot the error is this output
4
32
0
38
0
38
0
16
0
Error: For input string: ""

Here is my file:

```
Unit One
4
32 8
38 6
38 6
16 7

Unit Two
0

Unit Three
2
36 7
36 7

Unit Four
6
32 6.5
32 6.5
36 6.5
36 6.5
38 6.5
38 6.5

Unit Five
4
32 6.5
32 8
32 7
32 8

Unit Six
5
38 7
30 6.5
24 8
24 8
24 8

Unit Seven
0

Unit Eight
1
40 12

Unit Nine
5
24 8
24 6.5
30 6.5
24 7
32 7
```

And here is my code:

```
package question;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Weight
{
    

    
        public static void main(String[] args)//main method
        {
            try
            {
                
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                //System.out.print("Please enter proposed weight of stock : ");
                // int proposedWeight = input.nextInt();
                
                File file = new File("MathUnits.txt");
                System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
                FileInputStream ft = new FileInputStream(file);

                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(ft);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strline;

                while((strline = br.readLine()) != null)
                {   int i = 0;
                    if (strline.contains("Unit"))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                String[] numstrs = strline.split("\\s+"); // split by white space
                int[] nums = new int[numstrs.length];
                nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[i]);
                
                     for(int f = 0; f <numstrs.length; f++)
                     {
                    System.out.println(""+ nums[f]);
                     }
                    }
                    i ++;
                }
                //int x = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[0]);
               // int m = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[1]);
               // int b = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[2]);
               // int a = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[3]);
                  int a = 0;
                //   System.out.println("this >>" + x + "," + m +"," + b + "," + a);
                   
                //   if(proposedWeight < a)
                 //   {
                //       System.out.println("Stock is lighter than proposed and can hold easily"); 
                 //       System.exit(0);

                       
                //    }
                //    else if ( a == proposedWeight)
                //    { 
                        
                    //  System.out.println("Stock is equal to max");   
                    //  System.exit(0);
                  //  }
                  // else
                  // {
                    //   System.out.println("stock is too heavy");
                    //   System.exit(0);

                      
                 //  }
                   
                
                
        
                
                in.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            
            
            }
            

        }
```

Comment: Not sure which error you are referring to

Comment: try doing strline.split(" ");

Comment: added the error now i forgot to add it in it is this > 4
32
0
38
0
38
0
16
0
Error: For input string: "" 

it shouldnt have the 0's and the input string error also

Comment: I tried strline.split("") didnt work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One probable error I see

- You're not taking newlines into consideration, especially when you're doing a `nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[i]);` on an empty string

Also, I don't think you're getting the numbers into the array correct since you're getting only one int from each line, when some lines have two

Comment: do u know what the best way to take the empty line into consideration would be? Whats the best way to fix the array?

Comment: Add an if statement to check for a new line and for the array, you have the right idea in the code, check your nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[i]); and ask yourself, how many times will it run when you read one line? and how many times would you need it to run, look in the two lines above it (you'd prob just need a for loop)

Comment: ok i think I understand that part any idea why im getting the 0's in there?

Comment: it goes back to the not adding numbers into your array correctly, if you made an array of size 2, it defaults the values to zero. So if you only added one int from your line into the array, the other value in the array would still be zero because you never added the second value into it.

Comment: your output " 4 32 0 38 0 38 0 16 0" notice how the second value is never outputted correctly

Comment: yeh I see that I get what you mean so if i added 1 to an array of size 2 i would get 1, 0 - would be because ive set the nums array to numstrs.length thats giving me that problem, im just not sure why when im seperating the line by space that it doesnt give me the second integer in that line and put it into the array instead of the 0

Comment: you do get both integers, but you don't transfer them over into your int array, check how you use you int i and the line where you move the value into your int array. nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(numstrs[i]); moves one of the values, but the other value....

Comment: so i changed it and got the 0's out :) and all the right numbers up to 7 which is the new line and then i get an error saying input string"" Im still not sure how to deal with the line gap between them :/

Comment: add an if statement to check if hte current line is blank, if so then skip and read the next line